# Is it possible to do infix function composition in python without wrapping your functions in some decorator?

Tags: python, functional-programming, dsl, infix-notation

Title says it all. Seen lots of answers where folks have implemented `f @ g`, but this requires wrapping `f`, `g` in some `infix` decorator or class. Is it possible to get this to work? Maybe by patching some class that all functions are an instance of or something?

Basically I'd like to get this to work:

```py
f = lambda x: x
g = lambda y: y
def h(a): return a

# <magic>

z = f @ g @ h
assert z(1) == 1
```

Key here is that the magic above cannot be specific to/reassign `f`, `g`, or `h`.

Edit: Hey whoever closed this and linked that other question, that isn't what I'm asking at all? I am asking about pointfree function composition. More broadly, the answer to their question is yes, and it appears the answer to my question is no. I don't know how on earth this could be a duplicate if that's the case.

Comment: Is this question about implementing a language feature using Python or about Python itself? If the latter, is the `@` in your question the matrix multiplication operator (a.k.a. `__matmul__`) or something else?

Comment: It is `__matmul__`.

Comment: @lanf You wrote `z = f @ g @ h` where `f`, `g`, `h` are functions but you even don't call them?

Comment: Yes that is the point. Pointfree function composition is what I'm trying to achieve here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming

Comment: @InSync This question is not about implementing a language feature using Python. This is a question about Python itself.

Comment: @lanf I see. I think without wrapping/decorator is not possible.

Comment: No there is no such feature.

Comment: No, you cannot make a new operator work for the built-in `function` type, because it's built-in and there is nowhere to put the operator-overload logic. You can define your own wrapper type (the sorts of decorators you've seen) or you can use an ordinary higher-order function to do the composition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If I get your question right but as you said in your question you can *patch* the class and add `__matmul__` magic method. E.g.:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 10

# patch the A class to work with the `@` operator:
A.__matmul__ = lambda self, other: self.v * other.v

print(A() @ A())
```

Prints:

```
100
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'd like this to work for arbitrary functions, without wrapping them in a decorator. So the class we need to patch is the built-in `function` class, but I'm not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you want would require the builtin function type to have a `__matmul__` operator. Unfortunately it does not, and you can't add your own methods to builtin types.

This is why you have seen code that wraps the native functions in some other callable type (often using decorator syntax, since it's convenient). Here's my own version of such a decorator:

```
class Composable:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Composable):
            other = other.func
        return Composable(lambda *args, **kwargs: self.func(other(*args, **kwargs)))
```

You might be able to simplify this code a bit if your functions always have the same kind of signature (e.g. taking one positional-only argument). On the other hand, you might want to make things a bit more complicated and add code to proxy the function's `__name__` and `__doc__` attributes (and maybe some other attributes). A custom `__repr__` method would also be a really good idea.

Comment: "and you can't add your own methods to builtin types." not reasonably at least

Comment: Is there an unreasonable way to do it?